# How to create pdf file in node js

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, pdf, chart.js

I am creating an application in `node.js` utilizing the sails framework. I want to create a report in PDF format. The report needs to contain a chart generated using `chart.js`. The data is fetched from mongodb and displayed on a `canvas`. How can I create a PDF file of this chart using node.js?

Comment: @MihaiIorga
I tries pdfkit. But problem is how i can include the chart data(pie diagrom) which is generated using chart.js ? rest is working well.

Answer (score 10):

You can use **pdf-creator-node** package to create PDF

**Following are the steps to create PDF in Node Application**

1. Installation install the pdf creator package by the following command

> npm i pdf-creator-node

2. Add required packages and read HTML template

> //Required package
> var pdf = require("pdf-creator-node")
> var fs = require('fs')

> // Read HTML Template
> var html = fs.readFileSync('template.html', 'utf8')

3. Create your HTML Template

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
 <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>Hello world!</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>User List</h1>
        <ul>
            {{#each users}}
            <li>Name: {{this.name}}</li>
            <li>Age: {{this.age}}</li>
            <br>
        {{/each}}
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

4. Provide Format and Orientation as per your need

> "height": "10.5in", // allowed units: mm, cm, in, px
> "width": "8in", // allowed units: mm, cm, in, px

> or -

> "format": "Letter", // allowed units: A3, A4, A5, Legal, Letter, Tabloid
> "orientation": "portrait", // portrait or landscape

> var options = {
> format: "A3",
> orientation: "portrait",
> border: "10mm"
> };

5. Provide HTML, User data and pdf path for the output

```html
var users = [
    {
        name:"Shyam",
        age:"26"
    },
    {
        name:"Navjot",
        age:"26"
    },
    {
        name:"Vitthal",
        age:"26"
    }
]
var document = {
    html: html,
    data: {
        users: users
    },
    path: "./output.pdf"
};
```

6. After setting all parameters just pass document and options to pdf.create method.

```js
pdf.create(document, options)
    .then(res => {
        console.log(res)
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.error(error)
    });
```

Comment: This doesn't answer the original question of how to add dynamic content

Comment: Hi, efkah you can add dynamic content in HTML. please check README file https://www.npmjs.com/package/pdf-creator-node

Comment: I think he did provide dynamic content over here in example in answer, look at the users parameter in document object. I don't think anything more is needed, unless one wants him to write even the application logic.

Answer (score 7):

[`PDFKit`](http://pdfkit.org/).

Installation:

```
npm install pdfkit
```

Example:

```
var PDFDocument = require('pdfkit');

doc = new PDFDocument;    
doc.pipe(fs.createWriteStream('output.pdf'));    
doc.font('fonts/PalatinoBold.ttf').fontSize(25).text(100, 100);
```

Comment: where i should write this code? In controller or in js file @Nick Bull?

Comment: I tries this one. But problem is how i can include the chart data(pie diagrom) which is generated using chart.js ? rest is working well.

Comment: How does this answer the question of how to include the output of chart.js?

Answer (score 0):

**Disclaimer: the author of this post is the author of the module being recommended in the post.**

The simplest way to generate PDFs using NodeJS is to use the `pdf-master` package.
You can generate static and dynamic PDFs using HTML with one function call.

**Installation**

```
npm install pdf-master
```

Example

**Step 1** - Add required packages and generate a PDF

```
const express = require("express");
const pdfMaster = require("pdf-master");
const app = express();

app.get("", async (req, res) => {

  var PDF = await pdfMaster.generatePdf("template.hbs");

  res.contentType("application/pdf");
  res.status(200).send(PDF);
});
```

**generatePdf() syntax and parameters**

```
generatePdf(
  templatePath, //<string>
  data, //<object>   Pass data to template(optional)
  options //<object>   PDF format options(optional)
);
```

**Step 2** - Create your HTML Template (save the template with .hbs extension instead of .html)

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
      <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
      </head>
      <body>
        <h1>Hello World</h1>
      </body>
    </html>
```

**Render dynamic data in template and PDF format options**

```
const express = require("express");
const pdfMaster = require("pdf-master");

const app = express();

app.get("", async (req, res) => {

  var students = {
      {
          id: 1,
          name: "Sam",
          age: 21
      },
      {
          id: 2,
          name: "Jhon",
          age: 20
      },
      {
          id: 3,
          name: "Jim",
          age: 24
      }
  }

  let options = {
    displayHeaderFooter: true,
    format: "A4",
    headerTemplate: `<h3> Header </h3>`,
    footerTemplate: `<h3> Copyright 2023 </h3>`,
    margin: { top: "80px", bottom: "100px" },
  };

  let PDF = await pdfMaster.generatePdf("template.hbs", students, options);
  res.contentType("application/pdf");
  res.status(200).send(PDF);
});
```

To learn more about `pdf-master` [visit](https://github.com/chaitanyamogal/pdf-maker)

Comment: Where is the PDF file created? Is it possible to specify a path?