# How to extract attachements from a PDF in nodejs

Tags: node.js, pdf

I have limited knowledge in handling PDF:s and I need to extract an attached file from a PDF.

Comment: You can look at this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38767151/how-to-create-pdf-file-in-node-js

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you can do it using [pdf-lib](https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib) with:

```
import fs from 'fs';
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
import {
  PDFDocument,
  PDFName,
  PDFDict,
  PDFArray,
  PDFHexString,
  PDFString,
  PDFStream,
  decodePDFRawStream,
  PDFRawStream,
} from 'pdf-lib';

const extractRawAttachments = (pdfDoc: PDFDocument) => {
  if (!pdfDoc.catalog.has(PDFName.of('Names'))) return [];
  const Names = pdfDoc.catalog.lookup(PDFName.of('Names'), PDFDict);

  if (!Names.has(PDFName.of('EmbeddedFiles'))) return [];
  const EmbeddedFiles = Names.lookup(PDFName.of('EmbeddedFiles'), PDFDict);

  if (!EmbeddedFiles.has(PDFName.of('Names'))) return [];
  const EFNames = EmbeddedFiles.lookup(PDFName.of('Names'), PDFArray);

  const rawAttachments = [];
  for (let idx = 0, len = EFNames.size(); idx < len; idx += 2) {
    const fileName = EFNames.lookup(idx) as PDFHexString | PDFString;
    const fileSpec = EFNames.lookup(idx + 1, PDFDict);
    rawAttachments.push({ fileName, fileSpec });
  }

  return rawAttachments;
};

const extractAttachments = (pdfDoc: PDFDocument) => {
  const rawAttachments = extractRawAttachments(pdfDoc);
  return rawAttachments.map(({ fileName, fileSpec }) => {
    const stream = fileSpec
      .lookup(PDFName.of('EF'), PDFDict)
      .lookup(PDFName.of('F'), PDFStream) as PDFRawStream;
    return {
      name: fileName.decodeText(),
      data: decodePDFRawStream(stream).decode(),
    };
  });
};

(async () => {
  const pdfWithAttachments = await fetch(
    'https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib/files/4963252/with_attachment.pdf',
  ).then((res) => res.arrayBuffer());

  const pdfDoc = await PDFDocument.load(pdfWithAttachments);

  const attachments = extractAttachments(pdfDoc);

  const csv = attachments.find((attachment) => attachment.name === 'cars.csv')!;
  fs.writeFileSync('cars.csv', csv.data);
  console.log('CSV file written to ./cars.csv');

  const jpg = attachments.find((attachment) => attachment.name === 'mini.jpg')!;
  fs.writeFileSync('mini.jpg', jpg.data);
  console.log('JPG file written to ./mini.jpg');
})();
```

(found it [here](https://github.com/Hopding/pdf-lib/issues/534))